# Remove random sample to make group proportions match

Tags: r

I have a dataframe which has regional data, I'd like to be able to make the proportions within each country equal for a specific variable. Here is my example.
I have a table has the details of the sample, for Country by Gender. I'd like to be able to remove sample, with aim that 0 and 1 are equivalent.

```
> table(df$Gender , df$COUNTRY)
   
      1   2   3
  0  86  81 282
  1  21   7  23
```

Is there any package/function that will remove the values equal to zero to keep enough to match those equal 1?

This would be the desired result

```
> table(df$Gender , df$COUNTRY)
   
      1   2   3
  0  21   7  23
  1  21   7  23
```

If there is also a more basic way to do this, that will help too. For example, remove a random sample of 65 where df$Country=1 & df$Gender=0. I can then do each of country manually.

As someone requested a dput, here we go. The tables above have changed accordingly

```
df <- structure(list(Gender = c(1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
                                0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
                                0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 
                                1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
                                0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
                                1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
                                0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
                                0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
                                0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
                                0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
                                1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
                                0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
                                0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
                                0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
                                0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
                                1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
                                0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
                                0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 
                                1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
                                0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
                                0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
                                0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
                                0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
                                1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
                                0, 1, 1, 0, 0), COUNTRY = c(2, 3, 2, 1, 3, 3, 3, 2, 2, 3, 3, 
                                                            3, 3, 3, 3, 2, 3, 3, 1, 3, 3, 3, 3, 1, 2, 3, 2, 3, 1, 3, 2, 3, 
                                                            3, 3, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 2, 3, 2, 2, 1, 3, 3, 3, 2, 2, 3, 1, 1, 2, 
                                                            2, 1, 3, 3, 1, 2, 1, 3, 3, 3, 1, 1, 3, 3, 3, 1, 3, 2, 1, 3, 2, 
                                                            3, 3, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 1, 1, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 
                                                            3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 2, 3, 3, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 3, 1, 2, 1, 3, 
                                                            2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 1, 1, 3, 1, 1, 2, 
                                                            2, 3, 3, 1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 2, 3, 3, 1, 3, 3, 1, 3, 1, 1, 3, 3, 2, 
                                                            3, 1, 1, 1, 3, 3, 3, 2, 3, 3, 2, 3, 2, 1, 3, 2, 3, 1, 3, 2, 2, 
                                                            2, 3, 3, 2, 1, 3, 3, 3, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 1, 3, 3, 3, 2, 2, 
                                                            1, 1, 3, 1, 1, 1, 3, 3, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 3, 3, 3, 1, 3, 3, 2, 
                                                            3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 1, 3, 3, 2, 1, 1, 2, 3, 2, 3, 3, 3, 2, 2, 3, 3, 
                                                            3, 3, 1, 3, 2, 2, 1, 3, 2, 1, 3, 2, 3, 2, 3, 3, 2, 3, 2, 3, 3, 
                                                            3, 1, 3, 2, 1, 1, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 
                                                            3, 2, 1, 2, 1, 3, 1, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 1, 3, 1, 1, 3, 1, 3, 1, 1, 
                                                            3, 3, 1, 3, 1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 2, 3, 3, 2, 3, 3, 3, 
                                                            3, 3, 3, 3, 2, 3, 1, 3, 3, 3, 1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 
                                                            1, 3, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 3, 3, 3, 1, 3, 1, 3, 3, 3, 1, 1, 3, 2, 3, 
                                                            1, 3, 3, 3, 1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 1, 3, 1, 3, 1, 1, 3, 3, 3, 3, 1, 
                                                            3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 1, 1, 3, 3, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 1, 3, 3, 2, 3, 3, 1, 
                                                            3, 3, 3, 2, 3, 1, 3, 3, 1, 3, 2, 1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 2, 2, 
                                                            2, 3, 3, 2, 3, 3, 1, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 2, 1, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 
                                                            3, 1, 3, 1, 2, 3, 3, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 
                                                            1, 1, 3, 3, 3, 1, 3, 3, 1, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 1, 3, 3, 1, 3, 3, 3, 
                                                            3, 3, 2, 3, 2, 3)), row.names = c(NA, 500L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Could you please share some reproducible data using `dput`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a base R way.
First, table the data and compute the rows differences. Then, sample from the indices that have 1st column 0 and are equal to each table column name as many as those differences. These are the rows to remove.

```r
n <- 100L
set.seed(2023)
df1 <- data.frame(
  a = sample(0:1, n, TRUE, prob = c(3, 1)/4),
  b = sample(3, n, TRUE)
)

i <- df1$a == 0
table(df1) |>
  apply(2, diff) -> tmp
lapply(names(tmp), \(nm) {
  j <- which(i & df1$b == nm)
  sample(j, abs(tmp[nm]))
}) |> unlist() -> tmp

df1[-tmp, ] |> table()
#>    b
#> a    1  2  3
#>   0  8 10  8
#>   1  8 10  8
rm(tmp)  # tidy up
```

<sup>Created on 2023-08-08 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Answer (score 3):

The [`caret::downSample`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/caret/versions/6.0-94/topics/downSample) is practically tailored for this:

Some data:

```
z1 <- data.frame(gender = c(rep(0, 9155), rep(1, 2628)),
                country = 1)

z2  <- data.frame(gender = c(rep(0, 9335), rep(1, 1242)),
                  country = 2)

z3  <- data.frame(gender = c(rep(0, 31964), rep(1, 2720)),
                  country = 3)

z <- rbind(z1, z2, z3)

table(z)
#output
      country
gender     1     2     3
     0  9155  9335 31964
     1  2628  1242  2720
```

Apply down sampling where the `y` argument would be the interaction of the categorical variables you wish to use:

```
set.seed(123) #make it reproducible
z_down <- caret::downSample(z, as.factor(interaction(z$gender, z$country)))

table(z_down[names(z_down) != "Class"]) #remove added column
#output
      country
gender    1    2    3
     0 1242 1242 1242
     1 1242 1242 1242
```

This gives equal number of rows per categorical variable combo as in the combination with the lowest number of samples (1242).

If this is not desired, one can do by country:

```
lapply(split(z, z$country), \(x) caret::downSample(x, as.factor(x$gender))) -> z_2
```

then just combine the list of data frames into one:

```
z_2 <- do.call(rbind,  z_2)
```

and remove the column caret added:

```
z_2 <- z_2[, names(z_2) != "Class"] 

table( z_2)
#output
      country
gender    1    2    3
     0 2628 1242 2720
     1 2628 1242 2720
```

EDIT: I had some extra time so here is a function that does what you mention in the comment (proportion mix) since `caret::downSample` does not:

```
downSample_custm <- function(df,
                             factor,
                             by = rep(1, nrow(df)),
                             proportion = 1,
                             output = c("df", "index")){
  
  output <- match.arg(output)
  
  # split data.frame into a list using the by argument,
  # if by is not used it will just take the whole data.frame

  splited <- split(data.frame(df,
                              .factor = as.factor(factor),
                              row = 1:nrow(df)), by)
  
  lapply(splited, function(x){

    #get the number of instances of the minority class
    minClass <- min(table(x$.factor))

    #split input data.frame by class
    spl <- split(x, x$.factor)
    
    #loop over classes
    lapply(spl, function(i){

      #data.frame with class i
      y <- nrow(i) #number of rows 

      if(proportion >= 1 && y <= ceiling(minClass * proportion)){ 
        #if class has less instances then minClass * proportion return it all
        return(i)
        } else {
          #sample from class ceiling(minClass * proportion) times
          return(i[sample(seq_along(i[,1]), ceiling(minClass * proportion)),]) 
        }
      }) -> out1
    
    out1 <- do.call(rbind, out1)
    
    return(out1)
    
  }) -> out2
  
  out2 <- do.call(rbind, out2)
  
  rownames(out2) <- NULL
  
  if(output == "df"){
    return(out2[, !colnames(out2) %in% c(".factor", "row")])
  } else if (output == "index") {
    return(sort(out2$row))
  }
}
```

Usage:

down sample all classes:

```
z2 <- downSample_custm(z, factor = z$gender, by = z$country, proportion = 0.3) 

table(z2)
#output
      country
gender   1   2   3
     0 789 373 816
     1 789 373 816
```

down sample classes which are over represented:

```
z3 <- downSample_custm(z, factor = z$gender, by = z$country, proportion = 1.5) 

 table(z3)
#output
      country
gender    1    2    3
     0 3942 1863 4080
     1 2628 1242 2720
```

return row index instead of down sampled data.frame:

```
z4 <- downSample_custm(z, factor = z$gender, by = z$country, proportion = 1, output = "index") 

table(z[z4,])
#output
      country
gender    1    2    3
     0 2628 1242 2720
     1 2628 1242 2720
```

simple down sample (no by group):

```
z5 <- downSample_custm(z, factor = z$gender, proportion = 1)

table(z5$gender)
#output
   0    1 
6590 6590
```

Comment: Thanks! I need to look into this more. Does caret customizable to allow you choose any proportion mix, eg. 60/40? If so that would be very appealing.

Comment: Simplified the code for several steps.